# How to create a small widget with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, widget

I really don't know how to describe it, but if you understood it and had experience on that field, may be you can help me with something 'Open Source' and 'Ready-made'.

I want to create something like a box 'or widget', where you can change its content by hitting some buttons on the top of the box. (Hey the box is on a web page and this should use Ajax and Javascript).

I have tried some ready scritps, but I found them limited and they drive me crazy, JS frameworks also don't seems to offer such solution.
Any body have any idea on that field?

Comment: Expand your requirements a bit more.  Is this Box and buttons to be generated dynamically?  What should happen when a button is pressed what is the box updated with?

Comment: Are you looking for a dialog box type of thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because the box is on a Web page doesn't mean it should use AJAX, Omar.  Have you thought about using a third-party solution like [ClearSpring](http://www.clearspring.com/) or [WidgetBox](http://www.widgetbox.com/)?  If you need to put your widget onto Myspace, you'll want one of these.

That said, I've taken a couple of JavaScript-only runs at this problem; see [Twitterati](http://kentbrewster.com/twitterati) and [Put Your Digg In A Box](http://kentbrewster.com/put-your-digg-in-a-box) for examples, and my [Global Widget Summit](http://kentbrewster.com/widget-summit/) presentation for explanations.

Comment: I think u didn't understand well what I mean but the links are helpful

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Jquery?

Visit www.jquery.com

Some example can be found at
http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/

Also please check the In-place editing example at 
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable
http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Edit_in_Place_with_Ajax

Comment: yap but that need more coding is there something a little bit ready